# JS (p5.js) canvas multiplying bug and being drawn in weird resolution

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm experiencing a bug in my code that doubles the display and ends up drawing it twice, besides itself in a weird resolution. [After changing a global variable (total_sand) to a different integer, and changing it back, the display has actually tripled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtQgg.png)

The intended result is for it to display just once in full resolution (in this case, 301x301 pixels). This bug didn't happen immediately and seemed to happen randomly upon changing the code one day.

```
total_sand = 100000;
sandpiles = [];
var next_sandpiles;

function setup() {

    createCanvas(301, 301);

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        sandpiles[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            sandpiles[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    next_sandpiles = sandpiles;

    //STARTING CONDITIONS
    if (width % 2 == 0) {
        sandpiles[width/2][height/2] = total_sand;
    } else {
        sandpiles[(width-1)/2][(height-1)/2] = total_sand;
    }

}

function topple() {

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (sandpiles[x][y] > 3) {
                toppling = true;
                next_sandpiles[x][y] = next_sandpiles[x][y] - 4;
                if (x > 0) {
                    next_sandpiles[x-1][y]++;
                }
                if (x < width - 1) {
                    next_sandpiles[x+1][y]++;
                }
                if (y > 0) {
                    next_sandpiles[x][y-1]++;
                }
                if (y < height - 1) {
                    next_sandpiles[x][y+1]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sandpiles = next_sandpiles;
}

function update() {

    loadPixels();
    var r;
    var g;
    var b;

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (sandpiles[x][y] == int(0)) {
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 0;
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 1) {
                r = 0;
                g = 185;
                b = 63;
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 2) {
                r = 0;
                g = 104;
                b = 255;
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 3) {
                r = 122;
                g = 0;
                b = 229;
            } else {
                r = 255;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
            }

            var index = (x + y * width)*4;
            pixels[index] = r;
            pixels[index+1] = g;
            pixels[index+2] = b;
            pixels[index+3] = 255; // alpha

        }
    }

    updatePixels();
}

function draw() {

    background(0);

    topple();

    update();

}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Edited now, apologies.